# Why can't I use dragula in Vue3 setup but mounted?

Tags: vue.js, dragula

When I use dragula in vue3 setup. It isn't working. Like this:

```js
setup() {
    const dragFrom = ref(null);
    const dragTo = ref(null);
    onMounted(() => {
      dragula([dragFrom, dragTo], {
        copy: (el) => {
          console.log(el);
          return true;
        },
        accepts: () => {
          return true;
        },
      });
    });
    return { dragFrom, dragTo };
}
```

But this way can be successful:

```js
mounted() {
    const dragFrom = this.$refs.dragFrom;
    const dragTo = this.$refs.dragTo;
    dragula([dragFrom, dragTo], {
      copy: function (el, source) {
        console.log(el);
        return true;
      },
      accepts: function (el, target) {
        return true;
      },
    });
}
```

> Both methods are based on vue3.What's wrong?

Comment: You should probably await nextTick before attempting to instantiate dragula with your element references, since they’re not guaranteed to be non-null in the onmounted hook is invoked.

Comment: I tried what you said. It doesn't seem to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65087529/5962802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that you are not [accessing the **value** of the ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref), i.e. `dragFrom.value` and `dragTo.value` when passing them into the `dragula()` function. Remember that when you create a reactive and mutable `ref` object, you will need to access its inner value using the `.value` property.

This should therefore work:

```
setup() {
    const dragFrom = ref(null);
    const dragTo = ref(null);
    onMounted(() => {

      // Ensure you access the VALUE of the ref!
      dragula([dragFrom.value, dragTo.value], {
        copy: (el) => {
          console.log(el);
          return true;
        },
        accepts: () => {
          return true;
        },
      });
    });
    return { dragFrom, dragTo };
}
```

See proof-of-concept on this demo CodeSandbox I've created: https://uwgri.csb.app/